# How to avoid flickering when saving a row in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

Whenever I save the row in jqgrid, i can see the grid flickers with a brown background and then comes to the normal state.How can I remove this flickering effect?. I am using jqgrid 3.8.2.

Please help me.

Thanks,
Poorna.

Comment: What editing mode you use (form editing, inline editing, cell editing ,...)? Why you use so old version of jqGrid?

Comment: I use inline editing mode.It was an already developed tool with a few enhancements.So, I did not change the grid .